# Arquillian integration tests fail on Glassfish 4.1 container with secure admin (HTTPS) enabled

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, integration-testing, jboss-arquillian

I'm working on a project that makes use of Arquillian and Maven to perform integration tests against a remote Glassfish 4.1 container and a remote Wildfly 8.2 container. When the tests are running against the remote Wildfly container everything works fine, however when running against the remote Glassfish container the tests fail with a series of errors.

The Maven output reports an internal server error and also shows that the test failed due to a `NullPointerException` but I believe this is actually a result of the Shrinkwrap deployment not being deployed to the Glassfish container rather than an error in the code itself.

The Glassfish server log shows no sign of anything being deployed to the container but there is a `TimeoutException` recorded in the log file when the integration test is run.

What I don't understand is what I'm doing wrong that prevents the test running against a remote Glassfish 4.1 container. Given that the same test passes without any problems on a remote Wildfly 8.2 container, I believe the problem lies with the Arquillian configuration in my project rather than the code being tested.

**Update:** After some further investigation this appears to be a very specific problem with Glassfish 4.1 where secure admin (HTTPS) has been enabled. If I run the test on a Glassfish 4.1 container with secure admin disabled then the test succeeds. If I run the test on a Glassfish 4.0 container with secure admin enabled then the test also succeeds. Unfortunately Glassfish requires secure admin to be enabled to deploy to a container running on another host, so the only workaround I can see at the moment is to downgrade to Glassfish 4.0.

The relevant section of the `arquillian.xml` file is as follows:

```
<container qualifier="arquillian-glassfish-remote">
  <configuration>
    <property name="adminUser">xxxx</property>
    <property name="adminPassword">xxxx</property>
    <property name="adminHttps">true</property>
    <property name="adminHost">xxxx</property>
    <property name="adminPort">4848</property>
    <property name="target">server</property>
  </configuration>
  <protocol type="Servlet 3.0">
    <property name="host">xxxx</property>
    <property name="port">8080</property>
  </protocol>
</container>
```

The relevant section of the `pom.xml` file is as follows:

```
<dependencies>
  <!-- Java EE Dependencies -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Internal Dependencies -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-ejb</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Test Dependencies -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

...

<profile>
  <id>arquillian-glassfish-remote</id>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
      <artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-remote-3.1</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.CR4</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
          <includes>
            <include>**/IT*.java</include>
            <include>**/*IT.java</include>
            <include>**/*ITCase.java</include>
          </includes>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <arquillian.launch>arquillian-glassfish-remote</arquillian.launch>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
```

The relevant section of the parent `pom.xml` is as follows:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
      <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.8.Final</version>
      <scope>import</scope>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

The relevent section of the Maven output is as follows:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running myproject.test.whitebox.ejb.MyServiceIT
Jun 26, 2015 7:45:42 PM org.jboss.arquillian.container.glassfish.clientutils.GlassFishClientUtil getResponseMap
SEVERE:  [status: SERVER_ERROR reason: Internal Server Error]
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 101.582 sec <<< FAILURE! - in myproject.test.whitebox.ejb.MyServiceIT
myproject.test.whitebox.ejb.MyServiceIT  Time elapsed: 101.582 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.glassfish.clientutils.GlassFishClientUtil.getResponseMap(GlassFishClientUtil.java:163)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.glassfish.clientutils.GlassFishClientUtil.POSTMultiPartRequest(GlassFishClientUtil.java:131)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.glassfish.clientutils.GlassFishClientService.doDeploy(GlassFishClientService.java:245)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.glassfish.CommonGlassFishManager.deploy(CommonGlassFishManager.java:101)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.glassfish.remote_3_1.GlassFishRestDeployableContainer.deploy(GlassFishRestDeployableContainer.java:71)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$3.call(ContainerDeployController.java:161)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$3.call(ContainerDeployController.java:128)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.executeOperation(ContainerDeployController.java:271)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.deploy(ContainerDeployController.java:127)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.DeploymentExceptionHandler.verifyExpectedExceptionDuringDeploy(DeploymentExceptionHandler.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createDeploymentContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createContainerContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$1.perform(ContainerDeployController.java:95)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$1.perform(ContainerDeployController.java:80)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.forEachDeployment(ContainerDeployController.java:263)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.forEachManagedDeployment(ContainerDeployController.java:239)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.deployManaged(ContainerDeployController.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.execute(ContainerEventController.java:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.beforeClass(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:87)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:201)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:422)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:54)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:218)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:166)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)


Results :

Tests in error: 
  MyServiceIT.myproject.test.whitebox.ejb.MyServiceIT » NullPointer

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
```

The relevant section of the Glassfish `server.log` file is as follows:

```
[2015-06-26T19:52:25.713+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-REST-00003] [javax.enterprise.admin.rest] [tid: _ThreadID=225 _ThreadName=admin-listener(18)] [timeMillis: 1435344745713] [levelValue: 800] [[
  An error occurred while processing the request. Please see the server logs for details.
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer$ResponseWriter.rethrow(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:317)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer$ResponseWriter.failure(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:299)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:439)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:365)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter$2.service(RestAdapter.java:316)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:179)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:231)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:231)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransportFilter.handleRead(TCPNIOTransportFilter.java:90)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.TransportFilter.handleRead(TransportFilter.java:173)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.read(DefaultFilterChain.java:351)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainContext.read(FilterChainContext.java:695)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.BackChannelFilter.handleRead(BackChannelFilter.java:80)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.read(DefaultFilterChain.java:351)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainContext.read(FilterChainContext.java:695)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.BackChannelFilter.handleRead(BackChannelFilter.java:80)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.read(DefaultFilterChain.java:351)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainContext.read(FilterChainContext.java:695)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.InputBuffer.blockingRead(InputBuffer.java:1119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.io.ServerInputBuffer.blockingRead(ServerInputBuffer.java:95)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.InputBuffer.fill(InputBuffer.java:1143)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:353)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NIOInputStreamImpl.read(NIOInputStreamImpl.java:83)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.EntityInputStream.read(EntityInputStream.java:101)
        at org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEParser.fillBuf(MIMEParser.java:440)
        at org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEParser.readBody(MIMEParser.java:216)
        at org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEParser.access$600(MIMEParser.java:68)
        at org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEParser$MIMEEventIterator.next(MIMEParser.java:165)
        at org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEParser$MIMEEventIterator.next(MIMEParser.java:132)
        at org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEMessage.makeProgress(MIMEMessage.java:198)
        at org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEMessage.parseAll(MIMEMessage.java:181)
        at org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEMessage.getAttachments(MIMEMessage.java:106)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.MultiPartReaderClientSide.readMultiPart(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:225)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.MultiPartReaderServerSide.readMultiPart(MultiPartReaderServerSide.java:89)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.MultiPartReaderClientSide.readFrom(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:179)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.MultiPartReaderClientSide.readFrom(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:91)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.invokeReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:251)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:229)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:149)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:73)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:149)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1124)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:851)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:783)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest.readEntity(ContainerRequest.java:233)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.FormDataParamValueFactoryProvider.getEntity(FormDataParamValueFactoryProvider.java:369)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.FormDataParamValueFactoryProvider.access$000(FormDataParamValueFactoryProvider.java:86)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.FormDataParamValueFactoryProvider$FormDataMultiPartValueFactory.provide(FormDataParamValueFactoryProvider.java:309)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:81)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$AbstractMethodParamInvoker.getParamValues(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:121)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:387)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:331)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:103)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:271)
        ... 44 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.tmpselectors.TemporarySelectorReader.read(TemporarySelectorReader.java:126)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.tmpselectors.TemporarySelectorReader.read(TemporarySelectorReader.java:75)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.AbstractReader.read(AbstractReader.java:72)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransportFilter.handleRead(TCPNIOTransportFilter.java:77)
        ... 100 more
]]
```

Comment: Are the test in-container or client type? Add dependency to weld-api in the glassfish-remote to see possible exception through by your in-container test.  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId><artifactId>weld-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope></dependency>

Comment: The test is being run in-container. I've just tried re-running the test with the  `weld-api` dependency in the pom but it doesn't show any additional information in the Maven output.

Comment: Maybe there is a bug affecting the communication or/and authentication (you are over https also). Take a look at this http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24939/release-notes.htm#GSRLN00165 and  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24939/release-notes.htm#GSRLN00161. Sorry I don't have experience with remote glassfish

Comment: I think you're right, I've done some further investigation and this appears to only be an issue on Glassfish 4.1 where secure admin (https) has been enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of investigation I've found that this problem is caused by a bug in Grizzly version 2.3.15 which is bundled with Glassfish 4.1.

The issue is documented in https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21180 and https://java.net/jira/browse/GRIZZLY-1713.

I've tried copying a later version of the `nucleus-grizzly-all.jar` to the modules directory but Glassfish fails to start.

The best workaround around appears to be documented in [TimeoutException on remote Glassfish v4.1 deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26723273/timeoutexception-on-remote-glassfish-v4-1-deployment) which suggests downloading a patched version of `nucleus-grizzly-all.jar` from https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7319744/glassfish-4.1/nucleus-grizzly-all.jar.